# Sending tokens getting error

Tags: bignumber

Hi i deployed a token contract in ethereum and managed to interact with it. solidity code :

```
contract Token {
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;
  event TokenSent(address sender, address receiver, uint amount);
  function Token(uint supply) {
    if (supply == 0) supply = 10000;
    balances[msg.sender] = supply;
  }
  function send(address receiver, uint amount) returns (bool ok) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    TokenSent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    return true;
  }
}
```

now im trying to send tokens to an account and i keep getting the following error:

```
new BigNumber() not a number: [object Object]10[object Object]
    at raise (web3.js:14426:29)
    at web3.js:14414:33
    at BigNumber (web3.js:13442:67)
    at BigNumber (web3.js:13452:29)
    at web3.js:2241:16
    at web3.js:2252:21
    at web3.js:950:32
    at web3.js:1598:12
    at web3.js:707:16
    at web3.js:706:20
    at web3.js:3991:46
```

I'm sending the following:

```
myContractInstance.send([{"receiver": "ed7a39b8cd4c217f99af29b5e5d7cbfd3c53030d"},{"amount": "100"}]),
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Comment: Can you add the Solidity code of the token?

Comment: sure i edited it so its now there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call thus:

```
myContractInstance.send(
  "0xed7a39b8cd4c217f99af29b5e5d7cbfd3c53030d", // Better prefix with 0x
  100, // Just a number can work
  { from: tokenOwner }); // Rest of the transaction elements, if necessary.
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Rest of the transaction elements."?

Comment: This https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#parameters-24 transaction object. Minus `data: String`, which is populated with `.send( "0xed7a39b8cd4c217f99af29b5e5d7cbfd3c53030d", 100)`.

Comment: ah i see, so everything thats optional i dont have to send really am i right?

Comment: That's right. See if it works first.

Comment: now it says "invalid address" but atleast its different! :)

Comment: In `{ from: tokenOwner }`, you need to replace `tokenOwner` with the proper address of the token owner, and which you have in your node.

Comment: ye i replaced it to my token because i created it

Comment: Can you paste the whole command?

Comment: > myContractInstance.send("0x8b7cb5f2311f37f8ffd3501e8353cf69f290bf8f",100,{ from: '0xed7a39b8cd4c217f99af29b5e5d7cbfd3c53030d'});

Comment: How about `myContractInstance.balances("0xed7a39b8cd4c217f99af29b5e5d7cbfd3c53030d")` and `eth.getBalance("0xed7a39b8cd4c217f99af29b5e5d7cbfd3c53030d")`?

Comment: the first one says "invalid address" again and the second one works and shows me 971891495430357219404

Comment: Take the address of your contract: `myContractInstance.address`. And then do `eth.getCode(theAddress)`. Do you get `0x` or something bigger?

Comment: i get invalid too now when i use the address

Comment: How about `eth.getCode("0xed7a39b8cd4c217f99af29b5e5d7cbfd3c53030d")`?

Comment: i get 0x now like you said i should on the other 1

Comment: i reset my terminal and now i did eth.getCode("0x97ca476528AB7548B25f6cA8fe6418664F9610b2") and got a response with a long 0x address

Comment: ok it worked ! thank you so much this was the answer i just had to reset the terminal, thanks for sticking with me man i appericiate it alot

Comment: Cheers. Maybe you can paste the reset command here. Was it the shell's reset?

Comment: You might also want to consider implementing the [ERC20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20) standard so your token can be accessible to the Mist wallet.  The functionality of what you've called `send` is called `transfer` in ERC20.  Calling it `send` is a bit confusing given that `send` is already a standard function to send ether and not transfer tokens.

Comment: by reset i mean i restarted my computer and the terminal :), and thanks for the advice about the token standard! the contract i was trying was just me trying to do some basic things over the ethereum but its good to know there are conventions of how to deploy tokens